# Is the category of hypergraphs cartesian-closed?

Tags: ct.category-theory, hypergraph, cartesian-closed-categories

If $H_i = (V_i, E_i)$ for $i=1,2$ are [hypergraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) then a map $f:V_1\to V_2$ is said to be a *hypergraph homomorphism* if $f(e_1)\in E_2$ for all $e_1\in E_1$. Hypergraphs together with hypergraph homomorphisms form a category. Is this category [cartesian closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category)?

Comment: Do you have a hypergraph structure on $Hom(G_1,G_2)$ in mind? Maybe something drawn from category theory (since graphs are kinda like categories)?

Comment: Good point. How is it done in the category of graphs? Maybe for the category of graphs we could say that $f,g\in \text{Hom}(G,H)$ form an edge if $\{f(v),g(v)\}\in E(H)$ for all $v\in V(G)$. Analogously for hypergraphs, how about ${\cal S}\subseteq\text{Hom}(H_1, H_2)$ is a hyperedge in $\text{Hom}(H_1,H_2)$, iff $\{f(v): f\in {\cal S}\} \in E(H_2)$ for all $v\in V(H_1)$?

Comment: In this link it says Cat is cartesian closed, with functor categories as the internal hom. It says directed graphs are cartesian closed, probably using the same idea. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category

Comment: I take that previous link to suggest that the cartesian product on directed graphs makes it cartesian closed. There's also a cartesian product on graphs (link below) but I do not know if hom-tensor duality is satisfied. There's also a tensor product on graphs (link below): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302147/definition-of-tensor-product-of-graphs

Comment: Thanks @DavidWhite, I think the tensor product ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_graphsis ) the categorical product in the category of graphs

Comment: I remember from a course in grad school that there are 4 monoidal products on Graph, but I don't remember all of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is yes, although the internal-hom may be a little surprising.

First let's describe the cartesian product.  I believe the category $\rm HyGph$ is a [topological concrete category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+concrete+category) over $\rm Set$, in the following way.  Suppose $X$ is a set and $\{S_i\}$ is a family of hypergraphs, with functions $f_i : X \to V_{S_i}$ to their vertex sets.  Then there is a "largest hypergraph" on $X$ rendering the $f_i$ homomorphisms, where $E_X$ consists of all subsets $e\subseteq X$ such that $f_i(e)\in E_{S_i}$ for all $i$.  In particular, given hypergraphs $Y,Z$, if we take $X = V_Y \times V_Z$ with the $f$'s the projections, we obtain the product hypergraph structure on $V_Y\times V_Z = V_{Y\times Z}$: thus $E_{Y\times Z}$ consists of all subsets $e\subseteq V_Y\times V_Z$ such that $\pi_1(e)\in E_Y$ and $\pi_2(e)\in E_Z$.  Put differently, each edge of $Y\times Z$ is obtained by choosing an edge $e_Y\in E_Y$ and an edge $e_Z\in E_Z$, and then choosing a subset of the rectangle $e_Y \times e_Z \subseteq V_Y \times V_Z$ that projects onto both $e_Y$ and $e_Z$, i.e. contains at least one ordered pair with each possible first coordinate and at least one ordered pair with each possible second component.

Now there is a standard way to discover what an internal-hom must look like if it exists, by mapping out of small objects.  To start with, let $I$ be the hypergraph with one vertex and no edges.  Then for any hypergraph $X=(V_X,E_X)$, a homomorphism $I\to X$ simply picks out a vertex of $X$.  Thus, if there is an internal-hom $Y^X$, the vertices of $Y^X$ are in bijection with the homomorphisms $I\to Y^X$, which must in turn be in bijection with the homomorphisms $I\times X\to Y$.  But since $I$ has no edges, the above description of the product means that $I\times X$ has no edges either (in fact we could see this simply because any edge of $I\times X$ must project to an edge of $I$).  Thus *every* set-function from $V_{I\times X} \cong V_X$ to $V_Y$ determines a vertex of $Y^X$, whether or not it is a homomorphism.

The information about homomorphisms is instead carried by the unary edges (edges containing only one vertex).  The terminal hypergraph $1$ is a one-element set with the unique possible (unary) edge.  A homomorphism $1\to X$ picks out a vertex of $X$ *that belong to a unary edge*.  Thus, a homomorphism $1\to Y^X$ picks out such a vertex of $Y^X$, but such homomorphisms must be bijective to homomorphisms $1\times X \to Y$, i.e. $X\to Y$ since $1\times X \cong X$.  So the vertices of $Y^X$ are the arbitrary set-functions $V_X\to V_Y$, while the homomorphisms are the set-functions that belong to unary edges.  This is similar to some other examples of cartesian closed categories, such as $G\text{-}\rm Set$ in which the elements of $Y^X$ are arbitrary functions $X\to Y$, with $G$ acting by conjugation, so that the actual $G$-equivariant maps $X\to Y$ (the "real morphisms" in the category) are instead the $G$-fixed-points of the $G$-set $Y^X$.

We can detect all the other edges of $Y^X$ in a similar way.  For any nonempty set $A$, let $J_A$ be the hypergraph with vertices $A$ and the only edge being the whole set $A$.  Then a homomorphism $J_A\to X$ is a function $A\to X$ whose image is an edge.  Thus, an edge of $Y^X$ must be uniquely determined by picking a subset $A\subseteq V_{Y^X}$ of functions $V_X\to V_Y$ such that the corresponding function $A\times V_X \to V_Y$ is a homomorphism $J_A \times X\to Y$, which is to say such that for any edge $e_X\in E_X$, if a subset $e\subseteq A\times e_X$ projects onto both $A$ and $e_X$, then $\{ f(x) \mid (f,x)\in e \}$ is an edge of $Y$.

This defines a hypergraph $Y^X$ which *must be* the cartesian-closed exponential *if such exists*.  It remains to prove that it actually *is*, but I think this is fairly straightforward.  The evaluation map $Y^X\times X\to Y$ is a homomorphism, essentially by definition of the edges of $Y^X$.  And if $Z\times X\to Y$ is a homomorphism, then there is a unique induced function $V_Z\to V_{Y^X} = (V_Y)^{V_X}$, which is a homomorphism again essentially by definition of the edges of $Y^X$.