# "Infima" and "suprema" in the homomorphism preorder on hypergraphs on $\omega$

Tags: order-theory, infinite-combinatorics, lattice-theory, hypergraph

$\newcommand{Po}{{\cal P}(\omega)}$
$\newcommand{lh}{\leq_{\text{hom}}}$
If $H_i = (V_i, E_i)$ are [hypergraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) for $i = 1,2$, then a map $f:V_1 \to V_2$ is said to be a *(hypergraph) homomorphism* if $f(e_1) \in E_2$ for all $e_1 \in E_1$. We say $f:V_1\to V_2$  is an *isomorphism* if $f$ is a bijection and we have $e_1\in E_1$ if and only if $f(e_1) \in E_2$.

In this question we focus on hypergraphs $H=(\omega,E)$ (having base set $\omega$  and $E\subseteq \Po$).

For $E_1, E_2 \subseteq \Po$ we write $E_1 \lh E_2$ if there is a homomorphism $f:(\omega, E_1)\to (\omega, E_2)$.

**Questions.** Let $E_1, E_2 \subseteq \Po$.

1. Is there necessarily a set $E^* \in\Po$ with $E_1, E_2 \lh E^*$ and the following property?

> Whenever $E\subseteq \Po$ such that $E_1, E_2 \lh E$, then $E^* \lh E$.

2. Dually: Is there necessarily a set $E_* \in\Po$ with $E_*\lh E_1, E_2$ and the following property?

> Whenever $E\subseteq \Po$ such that $E\lh E_1, E_2$, then $E\lh E_*$.

Comment: Right - I don't know whether this is known for graphs - not even for finite ones! I should have made the scope of the question much smaller. I will write a new question soon with the focus on graphs, possibly just finite ones.

Comment: The disjoint union $H^*=H_1\sqcup H_2$ and the direct (tensor) product $H_*=H_1\times H_2$ have the desired properties.

Comment: The category-theoretic product, which is described [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/322107/508667), also has property 2. I don't know what the direct tensor product of two hypergraphs is, so I'm not sure if this is the same as bof's answer or not. These properties are direct consequences of the definitions of coproduct and product.

Comment: @pastebee It seems that "categorical product" is another name for the direct product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_graphs. It's defined so that the projection maps are homomorphisms.